# Let $A$, $B$ be square matrices such that $AB = BA$ . Then one has $(A + B) ^3= A^3 + 3(A^2)B + 3A(B^2) + B^3$ .

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$, $B$ be square matrices such that $AB = BA$ . Then one has $(A + B) ^3= A^3 + 3(A^2)B + 3A(B^2) + B^3$ .

Is this true?

I tested it and it turns out to be true so I'll assume it's true. But can someone explain theoretically why?

Also, I'm somewhat new to StackExchange. Would any of you mind telling me how to type with powers without the carrot and other stuff? Thanks :P

Comment: Use distributive law.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it is true.

You can just develop the expression to see it:

$$(A+B)^3=(A+B)(A+B)(A+B)=(A^2+AB+BA+B^2)(A+B)=(A^2+2AB+B^2)(A+B)$$

since $AB=BA$.

You can continue the computation this way to conclude.